# Помощь в анализе сайта

Tags: seo

Писал сайт для себя, занимаюсь его продвижением. Сайту более 6 лет. Добавляю контент регулярно. В сравнении с конкурентами в данной тематике мой сайт почти по всем показателям их превосходит. До недавнего времени он постепенно рос, поднялся до 2 страницы в гугле. Пару месяцев назад начал постепенно сползать вниз, сейчас на 18 странице. Ссылки не покупались. Массово по каталогам не прогонялся. Может кто то посмотреть и подсказать что с ним не так? [ссылка](http://conception.in.ua)

Comment: *можно ... порекомендовать https добавить - его сейчас любят поисковые системы - возможно из-за его отсутствия в последнее время стал понижаться рейтинг* — [Qwertiy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44306817#44306817)

Comment: данный пункт сейчас в работе, но среди лидеров в данной нише 50% не имеют шифрования https

Answer (score 5):

Ваш веб-сайт имеет следующие негативные сигналы для поискового ранжирования:

- Как уже сообщил вам Qwertiy – Arhad, ***ваш коммерческий веб-сайт не имеет SSL сертификата***. Этот сертификат подтверждает вас как владельца веб-сайт, подтверждает вашу локализацию. Это повышает доверие пользователей к вашему веб-сайту. Этот сертификат является **[сигналом Гугл для ранжирования в поиске](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html)**.
- ***Довольно низкая скорость загрузки для мобильных*** = **[4.888 секунд](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/180430_95_d933969b6c431f42782c0f754f8f5a79/)**. 
  В Интернете уже есть **[мобильный индекс Google](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/03/rolling-out-mobile-first-indexing.html)**. Ранжирование результатов поиска для вашего рабочего стола будет основано на сигналах мобильной версии. Скорость загрузки веб-страниц важна для мобильного трафика. Мобильные пользователи ожидают загрузки веб-страниц от 2 до 3 секунд. Мобильный трафик составляет примерно 57% всего веб-трафика. Таким образом, ваш веб-сайт и ваш бизнес теряют те же 57% трафика. Скорость загрузки мобильных устройств - это также **[сигнал Google для поискового ранга](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2018/01/using-page-speed-in-mobile-search.html)**. 
  Примените рекомендации Гугл **[Как улучшить индексирование, ориентированное на мобильные устройства](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing)**.
- Руководство Гугл **[Structured Data General Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** требует чтобы ***структурированные данные каждой отдельной веб-страницы представляли/отражали главное содержание этой веб-страницы***. Однако **[структурированные данные вашей первой веб-страницы](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Fconception.in.ua%2F)** противоречат этому руководству Гугл. 
  Главное содержание веб-страницы имеет информацию о студии дизайна домашнего интерьера. 
  Возможное решение: примените разметку для типа **[HomeAndConstructionBusiness](http://schema.org/HomeAndConstructionBusiness)**. Этот тип является уточняющим типом от типа **LocalBusiness** и **[поддерживается Гугл](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business)**.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в текстах, не понятно под какие запросы оптимизированы страницы. И насколько эти запросы распространены. Проверьте чтобы разные страницы не конкурировали между собой.

Проверьте облако частотности слов при семантическом анализе. Например [здесь](https://miratext.ru/seo_analiz_text)

Познакомьтесь с плагином Yoast SEO для WordPress - можете поставить на локальный сервер. Там эта проблема решается через фокусное ключевое слово - одно в бесплатной версии или до пяти в платной версии.